# ServerTransactionError: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON

Tags: nearprotocol

My smart contract is panicking and there seems to be some parsing error when I try to drive a certain function using the script. It was running fine previously.

```
Winnii@DESKTOP-1362D4P MINGW64 ~/RoulletteContract (main)
$ ./scripts/2.run.sh

$CONTRACT is dev-1644263134309-83139329126476
$OWNER is melchizedek.testnet

Scheduling a call: dev-1644263134309-83139329126476.joinGame({"_gameId":3856165906, "_guess":false}) with attached 10 NEAR
Doing account.functionCall()
Receipts: 77kKWs9L7adJvFAka1WWP91sP8ndPnhUCkJZMokchx76, CCELtSLD6WE6NAzBmoaxSM2d4Cw2yL4fvbt267dUS7Sk
        Log [dev-1644263134309-83139329126476]: joinGame() was called
        Log [dev-1644263134309-83139329126476]: ABORT: Cannot parse JSON, filename: "~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts" line: 144 col: 5
        Failure [dev-1644263134309-83139329126476]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON, filename: \"~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts\" line: 144 col: 5"}} 
ServerTransactionError: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON, 
filename: \"~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts\" line: 144 col: 5"}}
    at Object.parseResultError (C:\Users\Winnii\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\node_modules\near-api-js\lib\utils\rpc_errors.js:31:29)
    at Account.signAndSendTransactionV2 (C:\Users\Winnii\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\node_modules\near-api-js\lib\account.js:160:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async scheduleFunctionCall (C:\Users\Winnii\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\commands\call.js:57:38)
    at async Object.handler (C:\Users\Winnii\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\utils\exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
  type: 'FunctionCallError',
  context: undefined,
  index: 0,
  kind: {
    ExecutionError: 'Smart contract panicked: Cannot parse JSON, filename: "~lib/assemblyscript-json/decoder.ts" line: 144 col: 5'
  },
  transaction_outcome: {
    proof: [ [Object] ],
    block_hash: 'B5FeLa5KwXYs3JoDZ2nAWZoS5VpHRDXzVBqSZuYHrJw9',
    id: '6RKkc8x3H3YmQdHbrWzWRpBqTfHBia3SbhosdAcsjUpf',
    outcome: {
      logs: [],
      receipt_ids: [Array],
      gas_burnt: 2428021617030,
      tokens_burnt: '242802161703000000000',
      executor_id: 'melchizedek.testnet',
      status: [Object],
      metadata: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. If you provide some more information, it will be easier to help. Is it possible to post the contract code as well? Have you remembered to use the `@nearbingden` annotation on the class? Can you also write how you wrote the contract call? Did you use near-cli to call it?

Comment: It worked when I REMOVED @nearbindgen. I wasn't using the singleton pattern. Thanks